# Rails nested_form gem updates wrong parent data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, rubygems, nested

I have the following in one of my forms. With this code I can dynamically add divisions, sub_divisions and sub_sub_divisions on the page. The problem is the sub_sub_divisions I add are saved to the first sub_division even though they are correctly displayed on other sub_divisions on the view. I don't know what is happening between the view and what is passed to controller to make this error. Thanks a lot.

```
<%= nested_form_for @division do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <%= f.label t("name") %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
      </td>
      <td>
        <%= f.label t("description") %>
        <%= f.text_field :description, class: 'form-control' %>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><h3><%=t :sub_divisions %></h3></td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan=4>
        <table id="sub_divs" class="table table-condensed table-striped">
          <tr><th><%=t :name %></th><th><%=t :description %></th></tr>
          <%= f.fields_for :sub_divs, :wrapper => false do |sub_div| %>
            <tr class="fields">
              <td><%= sub_div.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %></td>
              <td><%= sub_div.text_field :description, class: 'form-control' %></td>
              <td><%= sub_div.link_to_remove t("delete") %></td>
            </tr>
              <td colspan=3>
                <table id="<%= 'sub_sub_divs' + sub_div.index.to_s %>">
                  <tr><th><%=t :name %></th><th><%=t :description %></th></tr>
                  <%= sub_div.fields_for :sub_sub_divs, 
                                          :wrapper => false do |sub_sub_div| %>
                    <tr class="fields">
                      <td><%= sub_sub_div.text_field :name,
                                         class: 'form-control' %></td>
                      <td><%= sub_sub_div.text_field :description, class:
                                                      'form-control' %></td>
                      <td><%= sub_sub_div.link_to_remove t("delete") %></td>
                      <td><%= sub_sub_div.hidden_field :id,
                              value: sub_sub_div.object.sub_div_id %></td>

                    </tr>
                  <% end %>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td colspan=3 class="pull-right">
                       <%= sub_div.link_to_add t("add") + 
                           t("sub") + t('sub') + t('div'), :sub_sub_divs,
                     :data => { :target => "#"+"sub_sub_divs" +     
                                #{sub_div.index.to_s}", id: sub_div.object.id} %>
               </td>
            </tr>
          <% end %>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan=2 class="pull-right">
           <%= f.link_to_add t("add") + t("sub") + t('div'),
             :sub_divs, :data => { :target => "#sub_divs"} %></td></tr>
    <tr><td><%= f.submit t("update"), class: "btn btn-primary" %></td></tr>
  </table>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Outside of your call to

```
<%= f.fields_for :sub_divs, :wrapper => false do |sub_div| %>
```

You should iterate over the sub_divs:

```
<%= @division.sub_divs.each do |sub_div| %>
```

And then pass each one to the `fields_for` call as the 2nd parameter:

```
<%= f.fields_for :sub_divs, sub_div, :wrapper => false do |sub_div| %>
```

Do the same for the next nested `sub_sub_div` and finally:

```
<%= sub_sub_div.hidden_field :id,
     value: sub_sub_div.object.sub_div_id %>
```

...will have the correct `sub_div_id`

Comment: Hi Diego, Thanks for the reply but it has not worked for me. I am trying to create new rows dynamically and the iteration <%= @division.sub_divs.each do |sub_div| %> fails with error message undefined method `values_at' for nil:NilClass

Comment: I assumed `sub_divs` was a relation on `@division`. You'll have to adapt that line to where ever you have your `sub_divs`

Comment: Thanks once more. I have made some progress in that now I know where it is going wrong. The dynamically added fields are not being built first. And I tried to do that according to the suggestion on the document as follows: <%= sub_div.link_to_add t("add"), :sub_sub_divs, :model_object => SubSubDiv.default, :data => { :target => "#"+"sub_sub_divs" + "#{sub_sub_div.index.to_s}", id: sub_div.object.id} %>   But then the error message tells me default is not defined